# Difference between NavigableSet, SortedSet and TreeSet in Java

Tags: java, set, treeset, sortedset

- A `TreeSet` puts an element in *natural ordering* or by the provided
  *comparator*.
- A `SortedSet` is also keeps the element in *natural order*

But what is the difference between them and `NavigableSet?`
Where are `NavigableSets` useful?

Some example to show its usage would be nice for beginners.

Comment: check out the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html), the NavigaleSet provides direct methods to get to the elements at the various location of the set. TreeSet is an implementation.

Comment: check this out : [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)

Comment: The question is vaild because the all the implementations of SortedSet in the JDK also implement NavigableSet. So why does SortedSet exist as a separate interface? None of the answers here address this, and I am not aware of a data structure that would be able to implement SortedSet but not NavigableSet (although it may exist).

Answer (score 29):

SortedSet is an interface (it defines the functionality) and Treeset is an implementation. NavigableSet is also an interface subtype of the SortedSet.

You can't just write `SortedSet<Integer> example = new SortedSet<Integer>();`

You can however write `SortedSet<Integer> example = new TreeSet<Integer>();`

As its name implies, NavigableSets are more useful for navigating through the set.

http://mrbool.com/overview-on-navigableset-subtype-of-java-collections/25417 offers a good tutorial on NavigableSets and some of the methods available when using one, that aren't available in a SortedSet.

Answer (score 3):

I hope you will find useful the following excerpt from [Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html) (see link to more details):

> Methods **lower**, **floor**, **ceiling**, and **higher**
>   return elements respectively less than, less than or equal, greater
>   than or equal, and greater than a given element.

Answer (score 3):

I feel [`this`](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/navigableset.html) is a well demonstrated reference with decent explanation.

Answer (score 3):

NavigableSet adds Navigation methods like descendingIterator() and descendingSet(), ceiling(), floor(), higher(), lower(), headSet(), tailSet(), subSet(), pollFirst() and pollLast().

Answer (score 3):

TreeSet implements NavigableSet, and (interface) NavigableSet extends SortedSet

Comment: Navigable set is extending SortedSet not implementing.